# How can I move a PyQt5 QTableView's verticalHeader to the right side?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to rearrange my QTableView so that the verticalHeader appears on the right like this:
[image]

I attempted this using a layout widget but my code below gave me this...
[image]

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QModelIndex, Qt
import sys


class MyTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data=[[]], parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data

    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation, role: int):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                return "Column " + str(section)
            else:
                return "Row " + str(section)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self.data[0])

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self.data)

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            col = index.column()
            return str(self.data[row][col])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    data = [[11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
            [21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
            [31, 32, 33, 34, 35]]

    model = MyTableModel(data)
    view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    view.setModel(model)

    gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
    gridLayout.addWidget(view, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    gridLayout.addWidget(view.verticalHeader(), 0, 1, 1, 1)

    container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    container.setLayout(gridLayout)
    container.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic (but imperfect) solution would be to set the [`layoutDirection`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#layoutDirection-prop) of the widget to `RightToLeft`:

```
view.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
```

If you still want to keep the text alignment to the left, you can return the *opposed* layout direction for the `TextAlignmentRole` (text alignment is relative to the `layoutDirection`, so if it is `RightToLeft`, returning a left alignment results in aligning to the right):

```
def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int):
    # ...
    if role == QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
        return QtCore.Qt.AlignRight
```

As noted in the comments, this has some drawbacks: the whole horizontal layout system will be inverted, which might result in unexpected behavior for the user.

You certainly should not try to reparent or move the item view's header by adding it to another widget's layout, as it won't work as expected.

Scroll areas have a [`setViewportMargins()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#setViewportMargins-1) function, but that is always overridden for item views (since its used to set the margins based on the contents of headers).

A possible (and, apparently, better than the above) solution is to subclass the table and override the [`updateGeometries()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#updateGeometries) function, so that we can call `setViewportMargins()` *afterwards*.

After that, you have to manually set the geometries of both headers, and also ensure that the *private* corner widget (the top-left "hidden" button that is used to select all items in the table) is correctly positioned.

```
class RightHeaderTable(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._cornerButton = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QAbstractButton)
        self._geometryRecursionBlock = False

    def updateGeometries(self):
        super().updateGeometries()
        # avoid recursive calls (important for interactively resized columns)
        if self._geometryRecursionBlock:
            return
        self._geometryRecursionBlock = True

        margins = self.viewportMargins()
        left = margins.left()
        margins.setRight(left)
        margins.setLeft(0)
        self.setViewportMargins(margins)

        vHeader = self.verticalHeader()
        geo = vHeader.geometry()
        geo.moveRight(self.viewport().geometry().right() + left)
        vHeader.setGeometry(geo)

        hHeader = self.horizontalHeader()
        geo = hHeader.geometry()
        geo.moveLeft(self.viewport().geometry().left())
        hHeader.setGeometry(geo)

        self._cornerButton.move(geo.width(), 0)

        self._geometryRecursionBlock = False
```

Note that this is a very basic implementation. You might probably notice some unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Looks like this also reverses the column order as a side effect, which wouldn't be acceptable for my application. If reparenting or putting the table's `verticalHeader` in layouts won't work I may need to just hide it and write my own

Comment: That would be unnecessarily complicated. You could reimplement the horizontal header section position instead.

Comment: There are also some other problems.. 1. Left clicking to autoresize resizes the column to the right of the click 2. Resizing the parent table locks the position at the right instead of left. I've tried overriding all these things but couldn't get a good result.

Would it be possible to do something like this instead of reversing the layoutDirection? https://dpaste.com/ARKCR8YXJ

Comment: @Esostack I've update the answer with a possibly more accurate solution.

Comment: @Esostack **never** do geometry operations (calling `resize`, `move` or `setGeometry`) within a `paintEvent`! Changing a widget geometry automatically causes an update request event; in the best case scenario it will result in multiple (and unnecessary) repaintings or undefined results, in the worst it might cause an infinite recursion.